# RabbitMQ Spring Java - RPC Pattern

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have some Spring applications that communicate between them using RabbitMQ as broker. I can send and receive messages asynchronously between them. But now, I need one application to send a message to another one and wait for the response. So, for this I am trying to implement the RPC pattern. It is working, but the problem is that I could only do it using temporary queues generated by Spring.

[image: rpc pattern]

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-spring-amqp.html

This is the code that sends the message and wait for the response.

```
public void send() {
    ....
    Integer response = (Integer) template.convertSendAndReceive(exchange.getName(), "rpc", "message");
    ...
}
```

When I send the message, the execution is blocked until the response is received and a temporary queue is created by Spring for the response, as expected.

But what I need is to use a specific and fixed queue, defined by me, to receive the responses. I need responses to be sent to an exchange with a routing key pointing to the fixed response queue (doing this I'll be able to send the responses to another queue too, that will be logging all responses).

I tried setting the "setReplyTo" property to the message, but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you using? With modern versions, direct reply_to is used by default, but you can revert to using a temporary queue by setting a property on the template.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#direct-reply-to

To use a named reply queue, see the documentation about how to set up a reply container, with the template as the message listener:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#message-correlation-with-a-reply-queue

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#reply-listener

**EDIT**

The template will block until the corresponding reply is passed into it by the reply container (or it times out).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So68986604Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68986604Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public String listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Bean
    Queue foo() {
        return new Queue("foo");
    }

    @Bean
    Queue replies() {
        return new Queue("foo.replies");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyContainer(ConnectionFactory cf, RabbitTemplate template) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        replyer.setQueueNames("foo.replies");
        replyer.setMessageListener(template);
        template.setReplyAddress("foo.replies");
        return replyer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(template.convertSendAndReceive("", "foo", "test"));
        };
    }
}
```

```
test
TEST
```

Comment: Well, I've already read that documentation but is not clear for me. I'm using the latest version of "Spring amqp Core" (2.3.10) and RabbitMQ Server (3.8.18), but maybe I don't understanding well. In fact, I could specify a named queue, and I defined a listener to receive the responses, and it worked, but I lost the syncronous way.
Is there a way to use this line to send the message, and wait for the response (blocking the execution) in a specific queue? Without the need to define a listener?

Integer response = (Integer) template.convertSendAndReceive(exchange.getName(), "rpc", "message");

Comment: The template will block until the corresponding reply is passed into it by the reply container (or it times out). I added a quick example to the answer.

Comment: It worked. That's exactly what I need. I was doing all right but I was missing the definition of the "SimpleMessageListenerContainer" (that was the part of the documentation that I didn't understand. Thanks!